# Re-enable "Always warn before previewing this type of file" in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, attachments

In Outlook 2013 message reading pane, there are several types of attachment previewers available (.pdf, .docx, .xlsx, ...). Besides the `Preview` button, there is also checkbox `Always warn before previewing this type of file.`. It is checked by default:

[image]

I have accidentally cleared that checkbox for PDF files, so now I have preview available immediately, without confirmation by `Preview` button. **How can I reset the checkbox back to checked state?** (I want to start previewer only after my confirmation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found [the answer](http://www.mydigitallife.info/reset-always-warn-before-previewing-this-type-of-file-setting-in-outlook-2007/).

Delete registry value `PONTState` from key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Previewers\pdf`:

[image]

The change is in effect immediately, **no restart** of Outlook is needed.